# Add timestamp excel with formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

In an Excel spreadsheet, I want to add a formula that when I type a text in a cell , it adds the current time after the text I type ( in the same cell ).

Comment: It's not possible without a macro. Formula can add content only to the cell where it's entered, and you can't have formula and type in the same cell.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following Worksheet event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count = 1 And Target.Value <> "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Value = Target.Value & " " & TimeValue(Now())
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Please don't take this the wrong way. I am only saying this for the sake of improvement and the good of the community. The [help] tells us we should avoid answering questions that *...are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem*. Yes, you have answered the vague question, but does the OP want a time stamp on every single entry into the sheet? That is why we should ask for clarification.

Comment: @CharlieRB ...............you have a point..........because the Poster did not specify that the behavior should be applied to a specific cell or a specific row or a specific column, I took the most general view.

Comment: I understand. That makes sense. You are doing great and have posted some wonderful answers. Unless the OP clarifies, we just won't know. Keep up the good work here.